# Some problems with post request

Tags: jquery

I still have some problems with jQuery. If I have html like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <textarea id="id_content" rows="10" cols="40" name="content"></textarea>
    <input id="yes" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<form method="post">
    <textarea id="id_content" rows="10" cols="40" name="content"></textarea>
    <input id="no" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<form method="post">
    <textarea id="id_content" rows="10" cols="40" name="content"></textarea>
    <input id="question" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Why can't I successfully post a request with this jQuery code?

```
$(function(){
    $('input').live('click', function(){
        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'yes'){
            var url = 'www.example.com/add_yes/' 
        } if ($(this).attr('id') == 'no'){
            var url = 'www.example.com/add_no/' 
        } else {
            var url = 'www.example.com/add_question/'} 

    var form = $('.' + $(this).attr('id'))
    var textarea = form.$('texarea[name="content"]').text().serialize()

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: textarea,
    success: succes,         
    dataType: 'json'
    })})})
```

And here is this code in jsfiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/3r9BL/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a unique class to all of your text area i am using class = 'content '

```
        <form method="post">
            <textarea id="id_content" rows="10" cols="40" class="content" name="content"></textarea>
            <input id="no" type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
        <form method="post">
            <textarea id="id_content" rows="10" cols="40" class="content" name="content"></textarea>
            <input id="question" type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
```

Then use this jquery code , this will solve your problem

```
    $(function(){        
          $('input').live('click', function(){
               if ($(this).attr('id') == 'yes'){
                    var url = 'www.example.com/add_yes/' 
               } if ($(this).attr('id') == 'no'){
                    var url = 'www.example.com/add_no/' 
               } else {
                    var url = 'www.example.com/add_question/'} 

          var textarea = $(this).parent().find(".content").val();

               $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: url,
                 data: textarea,
                 success: succes,         
                 dataType: 'json'
               });
         });
  });
```

Comment: sorry for answering so late, but i found more problems that i need to resolve. it is helpfull, Your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
var textarea = form.$('texarea[name="content"]').text().serialize()
```

with:

```
var textarea = form.find('texarea[name="content"]').text()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your html/code.

1) This line `var form = $('.' + $(this).attr('id'))` is looking for an element on the page with a class name matching the id of the clicked input button. As you have no elements with the classes `.no`, `.yes` or `.question` nothing will be found

2) The next line `var textarea = form.$('texarea[name="content"]')...` makes the mistake of trying to use this element in an incorrect way. I suspect what you really meant to do was `$('texarea[name="content"]',form)...` or `form.find('texarea[name="content"]')` both of whhich will find a textarea within the form discovered above.

3) textarea is mistyped in your selectors as texarea

Comment: sorry for answering so late, but i found more problems that i need to resolve